# Simultaneously modify window frame and view frame

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my application the user can hit a key to toggle between a large and a small window size. At the small size, the window is just large enough to contain a certain view. At the large size, the view becomes larger, preserving its aspect ratio, so that the view ends up being as tall as the window but not as wide. At the large size, the view needs to be centered in the window.

Right now I'm doing this in 2 steps: (1) resize the window, (2) resize and move the view. However, the user can see those 2 steps happening one after the other, instead of simultaneously. Is there a way to make it look as if the NSWindow and the NSView are being resized/moved simultaneously? Or some other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to accomplish this is to use [NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush). You would use it like this:

```
- (void) toggleWindowSize
{
    [ [ myView window ] disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush ];

    // Do stuff to change the size of the window and view.
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. (I also had to use -disableFlushWindow.)

Comment: @jlstrecker could you add some info ? for me it doesn't work.

Comment: @MatterGoal: You're animating the change. This question and answer are for instantly changing the size of both window and view in (what appears to the user to be) a single step.