# Animating simultaneously window and view frame in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I need to animate a view frame size adding 100px of height, but I need the window grow up simultaneously with the view.

I tried with this code :

```
    //resize Window
    NSRect winsize = [window frame];
    winsize.size.height += 100;
    [self.window setFrame:winsize display:YES animate:YES];

    //resize View
    NSRect viewsize = [myview frame];
    viewsize.size.height += 100;
    [[myview animator] setFrame:viewsize];
```

It works but I obtain an ugly effect, Window and View had some delay in resize. Thus, I get the Window frame resizing before than the View frame. 
How can I modify my code to make them resizing simultaneously ?

add: 
I found this answer but it tdoesn't seems to work for me:
[Simultaneously modify window frame and view frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988922/simultaneously-modify-window-frame-and-view-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good solution: using autoresizingMask to mantain min and max Y Margin and allow height resize. 
`[myview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable];`

Comment: This also makes your resizing behavior correct when the user resizes the window themselves.

Comment: Glad you found the correct solution. FYI The reason your original code doesn't work is because setFrame: blocks code execution until the window is done resizing.